# Why is my abstract base class's constructor not called when an object is initialized by the WCF deserializer?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

Question in title...   In short - I have a WCF service exposing operations that return entity classes. The client-side classes inherit from an abstract base class instead of the default System.Object. The abstract base class has a default constructor defined. When calling one of the service methods I would expect that constructor to get called when the datacontract serializer materialize the returned objects. However, the constructor is not called. If on the other hand I create an instance of the entity class myself then the abstract class constructor is called.

Why, oh why, and is there a workaround? Or did I miss something - is there another constructor signature that is called by the datacontract serializer when materializing objects? If not, how can the datacontract serializer materialize objects without calling the constructors the same way that a "new SomeClass()" call would do? Or did I drink too much coffee today (only had 2 or 3 cups so far)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WCF (and `DataContractSerializer` in particular) doesn't use constructors. No, really (it uses `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` to create raw objects).

It is expected that all data will be initialized either by the serializer, or for non-serialized fields - by serialization callbacks that you add (for example, via [`[OnDeserialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Wow. That surprises me. I thought that all object initialization would result in constructors being called. Oh well, I learnt something new today... :)

Comment: It is indeed rather surprising. I had to dig around in reflector the first time I saw it!

Comment: A follow up question [out of curiosity] would be: _why_ did they do it that way? Performance? To mess with our heads? Or some other better reason? :)

Comment: The constructor may do something inappropriate. They goal, with any sort of deserialisation, is not to 'create a new object', but 'get the old object back'. To do this, you may actively need to avoid the constructor.

Comment: Ok, so it is an attempt to protect us from ourselves then. :) It totally killed my productivity for the rest of the day. I'll finish this cup of coffee and then I'll go and have a beer instead... :)

Comment: Hmm. This is actually better. I can now have both constructor and a method tagged with OnDeserialized in the abstract base class. Not bad at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

I fully understand the reasons, however I do not understand why they do not support serialization callbacks in Silverlight. It seems to me, that in a WCF - Silverlight communication I cannot initialize my data contract without hacking myself. So, if I had a private member in my base class for internal use (eg. undo-redo behavior), cannot use the default constructor:

```
Stack<PropertyChange> UndoStack = new Stack<PropertyChange>();
```

This simply does not work. To make it work I should write something like this:

```
Stack<PropertyChange> _UndoStack;
Stack<PropertyChange> UndoStack
{
     get
     {
           return _UndoStack == null ? (_UndoStack = new Stack<PropertyChange>()) : _UndoStack;
     }
}
```

It seems a workaround to me. Anyone has better ideas?

Comment: This seems like a workaround, but you have to ensure tere is no race condition between the null check and the setter or else you may return a stale Stack for one thread. The only way I know to resolve this is at least to use OnDeserializing, create a `object syncRoot = new object()` and to lock on this in the UndoStack getter (or directly create the UndoStack instance in this method.